# Static library with third party framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-frameworks

I am trying to build a static library which is using a third party framework. It is built successfully.

But, the problem is, when i am including my static library into any sample application, the sample application is also asking for that third party library which is used under my static library.

Why the Sample application is asking for that framework, if it is already used inside by static library?

Comment: Did you include the headers from the framework in your sample application?

Comment: Yes, i have added my own framework's header in my sample app but not the third party framework's header because my framework is using that third party internally. If i am not including the third party framework into my sample app, it is giving me compilation errors for the third party classes. 

For additional information, i am using -all_load linker flag in my static library project and in my sample app project as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you have not used the "code" of lib(third party) during compilation and have used only .h files and .a file, then your library is dependent for executable code on the other static lib and hence it will be required.

the only way to remove the dependency is to compile the source of dependent(third party) static lib with your static lib code so the lib is generated having executable code of the dependent lib.

Comment: It showing me following error while compiling:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ThirdPartyCalss", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in MyStaticLib(SomeClass.o)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will some one.... but goto BuildSettings -> Architectuers -> Under BuildActiveArchitecture Only , there set NO and then generate library.